# Interchanging Derivative and Expectation without Dominated Convergence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, probability-limit-theorems

Let $Y$ be a continuous random variable in $\mathcal{L}^p(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ for every $p\in[1,\infty)$ and
let $f(x,t)$ be a continuous function,
$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
s.t.
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)$ is continuous and, for some $c>0$,
$$\left \lvert \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) \right\rvert < c 
\left \lvert x-t  \right\rvert^2 ~.$$
Is there any condition or theorem that allows interchanging the derivative and the integral as follows
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial t} \, \mathbb{E} \left[ f(Y,t) \right]
\overset{?}{=}
\mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{\partial }{\partial t} \, f(Y,t) \right] 
~~ ?
$$
The well-known *dominated convergence theorem* cannot be exploited because of the absence of a uniform bound on the derivative. I thought about *Vitali's convergence theorem* but, again, the uniform integrability hypothesis seems not to be satisfiable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This doesn't seem hopeful, at least to me. Your condition on the partial of $f$ won't even guarantee the expectation to be well-defined. $Y$ is only $L^1$ but the partial based on your condition means that $Y$ needs to be $L^2$

Comment: Sure, I tried to make the statement as simple as possible, but I clearly missed the crucial point you point out. Actually, in my framework $Y$ is a Gaussian random variable, so moments of all orders exist and are well defined. I proceed to edit the question. Thank you.

Comment: So then you can apply DCT, no? Now your derivative is dominated by $c|Y-t|^2$, which is inetgrable.

Comment: Sadly no, since DCT requires identifying a dominating function $g(x)$ s.t.
$$ \left\lvert \frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t} \right\rvert < g(x) ~~ \forall t ~~.$$

Comment: I don't think you need a global (in $t$) bound on $|\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}|$, just a local bound should be fine, right?

Comment: Yes, you only need a local bound. The difference quotient is equal to the derivative  by the mean value theorem. As long as you have a bound in some (non degenerate) neighborhood, no matter how small, you are good.

Comment: Alright guys, it definitely sounds reasonable! I just thought I couldn't work locally. Thank you very much